# Problems deploying a Vaadin App to production

Tags: java, npm, vaadin, production, vaadin-flow

I'm working with Java 8 and Vaadin 22. When I want to deploy my starter app to production by

```
mvnw clean package -Pproduction
```

I find several problems while it is building the frontend. It is continuously saying "Cannot find module 'name of module'". I try to install it with npm, but after doing so, there is a new module that is not found. I´ve also tried with `mvnw -Pproduction`, but the problem persists. I'm doing exactly the same things as other people who have no issues, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here are some photos of the problems: [cannot find call-bind module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ8sz.png) and
[cannot find css-select module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjMgc.png)

Comment: Can you run mvnw vaadin:dance before the build. and also move the project to a folder that is Boot sync by onedrive

Comment: Not not boot, sorry for the typo

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It really did the trick!!!! Entirely grateful!!

Comment: Please post and accept an Answer to your own Question, explains the whole solution, for posterity’s sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simon Martinelli said, running `vaadin:dance` in the command prompt and moving the folder out of the One Drive scope before `mvnw clean package -Pproduction` command was the solution to my problem